# What to do when 8 month baby is frustrated by crawling attempts

Tags: crawling

Our baby is 8 month old, and he can sit by himself, flip himself, and generally twist himself whichever way he wants to reach or look at something.

But he seems to be having a block when it comes to crawling: passive tummy time is fine, but as soon as he tries to crawl, he gets frustrated very fast by the efforts: he starts shouting very loudly continuously, and it can escalate to crying. He obviously wants to move around by himself, so we feel like we shouldn't just wait.

Trying to lift him to "show" him that he can put his knees under his body make him enter "being carried mode", and putting something under his belly instead tends to make him passive. We also try showing him by crawling ourselves, but that seems to trigger mild curiosity at best :)

What can we do to get him to practice crawling, without him getting instantly frustrated ?

Comment: My eldest first started crawling by crawling backwards! In any case, there is no magic bullet, he'll learn when he learns and meanwhile there's not a great deal you can do to stop him getting frustrated - that's just kids in general. What you could do is try to position him on all fours and gently move his hands and knees, see if he catches on after a while. But even then, expect him to get frustrated until he gets the hang of it (and even then!).

Answer (score 2):

Have patience.

Some babies learn to crawl late. Some don't crawl at all. It is frustrating until they get it, but they kind of have to get it themselves - there is no magic to help, although having a slightly older sibling or cousin does seem to help them get it faster.

Don't worry that it leads to crying - babies don't have any other way to communicate, so a cry doesn't mean the end of the world.